# Calling shell command from ruby with proper argument escaping

Tags: ruby, shell, escaping

I want to do the following securely

```
system "echo '#{params[:message]}' > /dev/log"
```

What is the **proper** way for escaping arguments when calling a native command?

(Example evil input: `'; rm -Rf *; echo 'I won.`)

Comment: The focus is the *proper escaping* not the *proper logging*. That is just an example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you do

```
system "echo", params[:message]
```

Then the second argument, will be sent as an argument, it will not be executed.

Comment: Excellent answer. I have to accept it and post a new question if I want to get a solution for my original problem.